# Not able to access variable declared in the buildtypes

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I am new to buildvariants in AndroidStudio and tried to follow several approaches found in the forums, but .....

I try to read a injected variable in the buildtypes from java.

- I have declared the variables appID & appID2 as String as follow:

build.gradle (app) :

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        resValue "String", "appID", "wgd"
        buildConfigField "String", "appID2", "wgd"
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.p

ro'
}
```

- I rebuilt the project.
- and I try to read that variables from the java code in my onCreate method

  code:

  ```
  System.out.println(R.string.appID);
  System.out.println(R.string.appID2);
  ```

but I get a SYMBOL COULD NOT RESOLVED ERROR.

Can someone help ?

*** UPDATE ***

I am a step further. 
I realized, that I have to choose the buildtype in lower left corner. I have done this and I can see now th file generated.xml for my release variant :

```
<item name="appID" type="String">1</item>
```

But it sais : Error : unsupported type String .

Any help ?

Comment: Try changing `resValue "String", "appID", "wgd"` to `resValue "string", "appID", "wgd"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the `buildConfigField` values via the `BuildConfig` class which will be automatically generated.

`BuildConfig.appID2` should return `wdg`

Comment: I guess I followed an outdated tutorial. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the Error : unsupported type String. issue:

> Try changing resValue "String", "appID", "wgd" to resValue "string", "appID", "wgd"

And to access the `buildConfigField` attributes use `BuildConfig.appID2`

More info: http://toastdroid.com/2014/03/28/customizing-your-build-with-gradle/